# Counting the weekday number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to count the weekday number in excel?

Let's say

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Aug 1 |  |
| Aug 2 | 1 |
| Aug 3 | 2 |
| Aug 20 | 15 |
| Aug 30 | 22 |
| Sep 1 | 1 |
| Sep 2 | 2 |
| Sep 3 | 3 |
| Sep 4 |  |
| Sep 5 |  |
| Sep 6 | 4 |

Aug 1 is a Sunday so it is blank, Aug 2 is a Monday and it's the first weekday of the month so it counts as number 1, Aug 3 as number 2, Aug 20 as number 15 all the way to Aug 31 which is number 22. Then it starts counting again the following month.

Can this be done without VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NETWORKDAYS to return the workdays and wrap in IF to get blank the weekends:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(A1-1,1)=A1,NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(A1,-1)+1,A1),"")
```

[image]

You can also provide a range in the option third criterion of NETWORKDAYS and WORKDAY to include a list of holidays to not count.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with NETWORKDAYS, I have to read up on it. Thanks for your help.